# Firebase ID token verification inside IUserIdProvider - SignalR - Firebase Admin SDK C#

Tags: firebase-authentication, signalr, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using Firebase authentication for my existing web API created on ASP.NET Core 3.1. I have to verify firebase user id token inside `GetUserId` method of `IUserIdProvider` interface.

**Server Side Codes:**

```
public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
     
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    { 

        /* Getting token from header when a SignalR client is connecting */
        string FirebaseUserIDToken = connection.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["token"];

        /* Decrypting firebase id token */
        FirebaseToken firebaseToken = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.VerifyIdTokenAsync(token);

        /* assigning firebase auth user id to SignalR user */
        return firebaseToken.Uid;

    }
}
```

the problem is `await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.VerifyIdTokenAsync(token)` is Asynchronous function and `GetUserId` does not support Asynchronous calls.

**Client Side Codes:**

```
hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("<my server>/testHub").withHeader("token", <firebase id token>).build();
```

For security reasons I can not simply attached firebase UID in the header instead of firebase id token.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution,

```
Task<FirebaseToken> task = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.VerifyIdTokenAsync("<ID Token Here>");
task.Wait(); //this did the trick.
string uid = task.Result.Uid;
```

If you want to verify if the task is successfully completed, use `task.IsCompletedSuccessfully` property.